# Error al imprimir apellido en programa para generar CURP

Tags: c, funciones

**Hola**, hoy haciendo un codigo el cual genera tu CURP (Clave Única de Registro de Población) me encontré con un problema al querer validar ciertas partes las cuales no pueden estar en los apellidos, lo que hace mi función es 'eliminar' esas partes de los apellidos, esto mediante una lista la cual la va recorriendo.
Mi problema esta en que cuando quiero 'eliminar' las partes de cierto apellido este no lo elimina por completo, dejando una 'S' al inicio del output. Dejo mi codigo y espero me puedan apoyar porque ya he intentado de TODO.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void omitirPartes(char apellido[], char partes[][4])
{
   for (int i = 0; partes[i][0] != '\0'; i++)
   {
       char *encontrado = strstr(apellido, partes[i]);
       while (encontrado != NULL)
       {
           int longitudParte = strlen(partes[i]);
           int longitudRestante = strlen(encontrado + longitudParte);

           for (int j = 0; j <= longitudRestante; j++)
           {
               encontrado[j] = encontrado[j + longitudParte];
           }

           encontrado = strstr(encontrado, partes[i]);
       }
   }
}

int main()
{
   char apellido[] = "DELASLOMAS";
   char partes[][4] = {"DA", "DAS", "DE", "DEL", "DER", "DI", "DIE", "DD", "Y", "EL", "LA", "LOS", "LAS", "LE", "LES", "MAC", "MC", "VAN", "VON"};

   omitirPartes(apellido, partes);

   printf("%s\n", apellido);
   return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT CON `char apellido[] = "DELASLOMAS";`: SLOMAS
OUTPUT CON `char apellido[] = "DELOSLOMAS";`: LOMAS
NOTA: Esto solo pasa con partes como 'LAS' o 'LES', porque intente con 'LOS' y esa parte si la omite correctamente. Graciaaas.

Comment: Una observacion, `"..., LA", "LOS", "LAS", "LE", "LES",...]`, si vas eliminando partes de la cadena siguiendo el orden definido en este array, para cuando llega la hora de buscar `"LES"` o `"LAS"`, solo queda la `S` en ella,  porque en los pasos previos ya has eliminado `"LE"`/`"LA"`. Funciona con `"LOS"` porque no defines una cadena `"LO"` en tu array  **antes** de `"LOS"` como ocurre con `"LE"/"LES"` y `"LA"/"LAS"`. Utilizando un termino usado en regex, tu búsqueda debería ser "greedy" (avariciosa), por ejemplo, debería buscar y eliminar "LES" antes de "LE"...

Comment: No me habia percatado de eso, me acabas de salvar la vida. ¡Gracias!